# Using StringBuilder for very few concatenations

Tags: vb.net

Everyone (or everyone who has been taught) knows that [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) is the way to go for dynamically building a string with many concatenations.

Due to (I must confess) mostly laziness, if I am doing a few concatenations (say, around 3), I will use a plain old String.  I guess I just can't handle having that extra instantiation and toString.

Is using a plain old String in this scenario poor practice?  Is there any extra overhead for using a StringBuilder vs. a String in this context, or would StringBuilder still be more efficient?

Specific Examples:

```
    Dim PractitionerName As String = CurrentApplicant.FirstName
    If CurrentApplicant.Demographics.MiddleInitial <> "" Then
        PractitionerName &= " " & CurrentApplicant.Demographics.MiddleInitial
    End If
    If CurrentApplicant.LastName <> "" Then
        PractitionerName &= " " & CurrentApplicant.LastName
    End If

    Dim Endorsements As String = ""
    For Each Endorsement As IowaLicensure.LicenseEndorsement In PractitionerLicense.LicenseEndorsements
        Endorsements &= Endorsement.EndorsementType.Description & VbCrLf
    Next
```

Comment: there may be other alternatives depending on the details (not supplied); for instance creating one string, once from the parts.

Comment: Should be easy enough to test.

Comment: @Plutonix, in once case I am conditionally concatenating some stuff in a pair of If statements, in another I am using a for loop over a dataset which will in the context should never be more than a half dozen or so and usually about 0-2 (since they are endorsements on a teaching license)

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, not sure how I would set up / observe such a test (we don't use a code profiler, etc.)  Any ideas or resources you could point me towards?

Comment: If you only concatenate 3 strings, I would say that the performance difference will be very minimum. Depends on how much you do it per seconds.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those cases where performance doesn't really matter (filling out a single PDF form on demand in a web app).  It more just "feels" wrong, and I'm curious what others do in similar situations.

Comment: For your info http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-performance and also http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat

Comment: @Steve, exactly the kind of info I was looking for!  Thanks!

Comment: @TravisMiller it is just a starting point. If you are really concerned about performances you should do your benchmarks in your real scenario. A mandatory reading [Which is Faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) from E.Lippert the C# boss :-)

Comment: I've read (don't remember where) that for one-off concatenations, stringbuilder is overkill (after all the compiler may well optimize it into one big string anyway). The part that concerns me is your statement of "should never be more than a dozen..." Just like no one will ever need more than 640K of RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devil is in the details, but you may be able to use something like this in some cases:

```
If bePolite Then
    Return String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", Title, FirstN, MiddleI, LastN)
    ' "Doctor Jonas K Salk"
Else
    Return String.Format("{0}, {1}", LastN, FirstN) 
    ' "Jones, Sally"
End If
```

The For Each scenario is trickier but something similar can sometimes be done from one of the underlying classes.  In most cases, not much will likely be saved unless there is a larger loop iterating.

Comment: LOL, I actually started out with your first String.Format line until I realized it looked silly without a middle name.  I went away from the approach once I realized I'd need an If statement anyway, but it ends up looking cleaner (and maybe a hair more efficient?) anyyway.  I like it!

Comment: a mask of `"{0} {1}{2}{3}"` could be used if a helper formatted the MI to `" K. "` or `" "` when there isnt a MI: "Dr Jonas K. Salk" or "Dr Jonas Salk"

Comment: BTW efficiency be damned: I think it is easier to read/debug (where appropriate) than a block of IFs and ` &= ` statements

Comment: @Duston I think you posted to the wrong post.  I am not using StringBuilder and said nothing about a dozen - that was the OP in a comment up above.

Comment: @Duston, generally I would be concerned about such a statement too.  But the variable is limited by the context of the application's domain.  An endorsement on a license is like taking a minor while pursuing a degree.  I've never heard of anyone having 500 minors, but maybe I'll be proven wrong.

Comment: Oh, and BTW @Plutonix, if I wasn't clear, I agree: performance is probably not a concern in this context and I like yours better from a readability standpoint :-)